# "Increasing/growing/enhancing the response time" — with the meaning of "making bigger"

Tags: word-choice, difference, verbs, collocations

I would like to say that some actions I take will make the "response time" bigger. In other words, the delay will be bigger.

Some options came to my head, but I don't know which one I should use.

- Increasing the response time
- Growing the response time
- Enhancing the response time

Comment: *Increasing*.  By the way, this question would be less confusing if you changed *growling* to *growing*.

Comment: *Increasing* will work, but also *lengthening* or if you want to say that an increase in the response time is a bad thing, then *hurting*, *worsening*.  Or if increased response time is a good thing then, *improving* or *helping*

Comment: Note you have probably miss-spelled 'growing' here. Growling is the noise a dog might make when angry whilst growing is something plants do.

Comment: *Turn* is used of causing changes in orientation and color, but not size: you *make* something bigger or smaller. And while *grow* is used as a causative in agriculture and business, that sense is not current in other fields.

Answer (score 3):

As Snailplane noted in a comment, the correct word in this case is *increase*:

> Old response time: X time units
>
> New response time: X+Y time units

The response time is greater than it was before the change, so it has *increased*:

> After implementing the new system, response time has increased.

However, this can be ambiguous. Not because of the meanings of the English words, but because of how readers interpret them. In a number of contexts, an *increase* is positive:

> Our earnings have increased 5% over last quarter
>
> Hard drive capacity has increased greatly over the last ten years.

It is possible that readers will see the word *increase* and ignore context, instead just assuming that it's a positive. To avoid this, use a word like *worsen* or *hurt*, as Jim noted in another comment. These words are unquestionably negative without any ambiguity.